# Set selected value from database

Tags: php, jquery

I have the below code and I'm stuck finding solution for my problem. I want to select a value from a dropdown menu according on what the PHP result is.

```
<form>
    <select name="filter" id="filter">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="AT_001">AT_001</option>
        <option value="GG_001">GG_001</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="reference" id="reference"><br><br>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

```js
$("#filter").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "getdata.php",
        data : {
            "id" : id
        },
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#name").val(data.fname);
            $("#reference").val(data.reference);
            $("#gender").attr("", data.gender); // ????? <--
        }
    });
});
```

```php
$id = $_POST['id'];    

$query = "SELECT fname, reference FROM tb_amity WHERE coc = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of errors?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: You should query gender field from database together with fname  and reference

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali it works man! i just forgot to. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `val()` to set the selected option of a `select` element:

```
$("#gender").val(data.gender);
```

This is assuming that the `data.gender` value returned by your PHP is either `'Male'` or `'Female'`

Answer (score 0):

First console what you are getting inside 'data.gender', if its value is present inside your options value then it works fine like:

```
$("#gender").val(data.gender);
```